# Execute 2 mysql Queries with the second being based on the first

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Hi I have two tables that I need to insert into.

the issue is that the first table has an ID field that is automatically generated and I need this field in the second query

members (table1):

### |id|name|eyeColour|

assignedMembers (table 2):

### |id|memberID|groupID|

I am currently using the below:

```
$addMember = $dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO members(name,date)     VALUES(?,?)");
$addMember->bind_param("ss",$name,$eyeColour);
$addMember->execute();

$getID = $dbHandle->("SELECT id from members where name = ? LIMIT 1");
$getID->bind_param("s",$name);
$getID->execute();
$getID->bind_param($MID);

$assignMember= $dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO assignedMembers memberID,groupID) VALUES(?,4)");
$assignMember->bind_param("i",$MID);
$assignMember->execute();
```

This fails at the $assignMember->bind_param(); after troubleshooting I noticed that the $MID variable is empty.

it seems as though the row from the first INSERT is not added before the execution of the next statement is there a way to force this?

Thank you for taking the time to read this post, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what is $dbHandle? PDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysqli:$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) is what you are looking for.

```
$addMember = $dbHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO members(name,date)     VALUES(?,?)");
$addMember->bind_param("ss",$name,$eyeColour);
$addMember->execute();

$id = $dbHandle->insert_id;
```

Comment: what kind of syntax is this? `$getID = $dbHandle->("...");`

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake there. i updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
$getID->bind_result($MID);
$getID->fetch();
```

instead of

```
$getID->bind_param($MID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to usage of '...->bind_param' I assume, you use MySQLi.
Check out: [mysqli_insert_id — Get the ID generated in the last query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: you asume he's using mysqli but tell him to use the mysql_ function and not the mysqli_ one?

Comment: the linked resource is the msqli_one. edited the link itself, thx for hint.